# Mouse clicks unresponsive when combobox action event is fired and breakpoint is inside that event while in debug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx, freeze

Specs:

```
System:         Kubuntu 20.04 (Debian family, KDE desktop manager)
JavaFX version: 17.0.1
Eclipse:        2022-03
JVM:            Temurin 11 (OpenJDK)
```

How to reproduce:

1. Add an event for some Combobox (code below is whole-class example)

   ```
   public class Main extends Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       ComboBox<Integer> combo = new ComboBox<>();
       combo.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3);
       combo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               System.out.println("test");
           }
       });
       Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(combo));
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.setWidth(400);
       primaryStage.setHeight(400);
       primaryStage.show();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add breakpoint inside that event method (handle).
3. Start the JavaFX application from Eclipse in debug mode.
4. Select something from Combobox, so the event is fired.
5. Feel that you can not click on anything (In whole OS. Not just application, which is expected when there is breakpoint and execution stop)

All I can do is start System Manager using the keyboard and kill that application. Have not tried on another Linux. This might happen only on Kubuntu or KDE desktop manager or using only the specs above.

Comment: @kleopatra Maybe I did not explain clearly... Well yes the execution is expected to sit on a breakpoint there, but mouse clicks are unresponsive in whole operating system. I did not mean only in that javafx application. I mean once breakpoint is there and event is fired can't click anywhere whether its Eclipse, OS taskbar, that application. Simple cant do anything with mouse except movement.

Comment: just fyi: worksforme in win10/eclipse/fx17

Comment: @kleopatra yeah seems like linux or just kubuntu issue

Comment: Also works on macOS. I can click anywhere I like and even Eclipse is still responsive although it is halted at the breakpoint.

Comment: Same on MacOS command line; while unlikely, consider adding imports.

Comment: Not a new problem in Linux (I ran into this in like 20 years ago), possibly related to how UI event queues work. Technically you've stopped in the middle of the a GUI event, so *weird things* can happen when you're in the same display.